# AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'Get' while making a GET request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a Get request , but am getting this error :

```
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'Get'
```

Below is my code :

```
class VerifyEmail(APIView):
    """Verify user account."""

    serializer_class = EmailVerificationSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        """Obtain email token."""
        token = request.Get.get('token')
        payload = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY)
```

In the `urls.py` :

```
path('email-verify/', views.VerifyEmail.as_view(), name='email-verify'),
```

The issue is on this line :

```
token = request.Get.get('token')
```

What could be the issue for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`token = request.Get.get('token')`

this should be
`token = request.GET.get('token')`

GET in all capital